# Creating a separate file for main, interface and class

Tags: c#, class, interface

I'm starting to learn how to create C# and using Interface and Class.
Can someone teach me how to separate my Class and my Interface and still maintain their connection from one another?

Reason: If I'll be updating my code, I'll know where to add them and it will be less code in my screen.

```
namespace Car
{
    class MainClass
    {

        //My Interface
        interface ICar
        {
            int gas { get; set; }

            //void refuel();

            int getGasLeft();
        }

        //My Class
        class Car : ICar
        {
            public int gas { get; set; }

            public Car(string _name)
            {
                name = _name;
                dist = 0;
                gas = 40;
            }


            public void refuel(int lit)
            {
                gas += lit;
            }


            public int getGasLeft()
            {
                return gas;
            }



        }

        //Main
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car toyota = new Car();
            toyota.drive(100);
            toyota.refuel(5);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + toyota.name +
                              "\nGas Left: " + toyota.getGasLeft());

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, a *namespace* is the way to connect files from different places.

For example, you can make a folder `Interfaces` and put your `ICar` there. I will show you an example from my project.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

In my `ViewModel.cs` I use an object named `FakeData`. As you can see below, class `FakeData` is in the `TaskManager.Models` namespace.

[image]

Now, we are going to our project and we are looking at the `Models` folder.

In C#, when you create a folder and a class in it, you will get a `namespace` based on your folder name. Of course, you can change it. You can edit the namespace how you want to.

[image]

In your case, you can simply make a folder called `Interfaces`. Right click, then select New Class, and give it a name, for example, `Icar.cs`. Paste your code there. Your default namespace will be `ProjectName.Interfaces`. Make your interface `public`. Then, you can call your interface by adding `using ProjectName.Interfaces` in the top of your main class. Then you can do `Main : ICar` without any errors.

Same idea with the `Car` class. You can make a folder named `Models` and a class in it that called `Cars.cs`. It will have the namespace `ProjectName.Models`. If you want to use your interface that is in `Interfaces` folder, you need to add a namespace to your `Car.cs` class. In your case, it will look like `using ProjectName.Interfaces`. Then, you can call the interface in `Car.cs` without any error.

Feel free to ask me any questions about this. I will try to help you.

Comment: Whoa, that's really well detailed @michasauces. Can you criticize my class and see its vulnerability? The reason behind this idea is for me to further understand how main should not know how the things are being done in back end.

Comment: I will look at it in a few hours, because now i dont have too much time.

Comment: If my answer is ok with your question, could u approve it by markin in?

Comment: Sure thing! Done. I'll wait for your response then :) Thanks

Comment: You dont need folders that i mentioned before, But it will help \in navigate and it is good practice. When you make `.cs` file in project directory (rightclick on project, then simply add new item) the `.cs` files will have same namespace, for example `ProjectName`. So you dont need to using `using namespace` in your class, because files sees each other in the same namespace. If Car and Main will be in same namespace, u dont need to use `using`. Just call object from that class and u will be ok

Comment: @Maku if you want ask for a code review, go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about public, private, protected, namespaces, and so on.

On your case, create a new file called ICar.cs in the same folder and declare it as public interface in the same namespace.

Comment: Yup, that's also what I'm testing @DaeMoohn, I already added two files separating main, class and interface. By the way, can you criticize how I use protection levels and if there's a way for the main to never know how everything was done inside class?